# C# get value from class into mainForm

Tags: c#, forms, class, oop

I have the following class:

```
    public class CreateNewWeapon : BaseWeapon
{

    string[] weaponNames = { "Dragonslayer", "SoopaDoopa", "Mastersword" };

    private BaseWeapon newWeapon;

    public void CreateWeapon()
    {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = rnd.Next(0, weaponNames.Length);

        newWeapon = new BaseWeapon();

        newWeapon.ItemName = weaponNames[x];
        newWeapon.Strength = rnd.Next(0, 5);
        newWeapon.Vitality = rnd.Next(0, 5);
        newWeapon.Intelligence = rnd.Next(0, 5);
    }

}
```

And would like to get the values in my main form, setting a label in a second form like this:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        newWep = new Items.CreateNewWeapon();

        newWep.CreateWeapon();

        ShowWeapon shWep = new ShowWeapon();

        shWep.Label6 = newWep.Strength.ToString();
        shWep.Visible = true;
    }
```

But the values don't get transfered even to the first Form, where do they get lost?

Comment: ShowWeapon is a form?

Comment: yes, ShowWeapon is actually a Form. I try to keep it to the details: Separate class does the CreateWeapon() method. Form1 (main) calls the function with its own instance of the class and tries to set the ShowWeapon.Label6 (set) to the value. But the value is already lost and always displays 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. *private BaseWeapon newWeapon;* 
   When you declare a variable as *private*, it is not accessible by any object outside the *CreateNewWeapon* class.
2. *public void CreateWeapon()* The return value of your method is void. You should change it into *BaseWeapon* and return the *newWeapon* to the caller

I think you should change your code into this:

```
public class CreateNewWeapon : BaseWeapon
{

    string[] weaponNames = { "Dragonslayer", "SoopaDoopa", "Mastersword" };

    public BaseWeapon CreateWeapon()
    {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = rnd.Next(0, weaponNames.Length);

        var newWeapon = new BaseWeapon();

        newWeapon.ItemName = weaponNames[x];
        newWeapon.Strength = rnd.Next(0, 5);
        newWeapon.Vitality = rnd.Next(0, 5);
        newWeapon.Intelligence = rnd.Next(0, 5);

        return newWeapon;
    }

}
```

and in the button2_Click method, call it this way:

```
var weapon = newWep.CreateWeapon();
```

Comment: P.S.: What is the "var" keyword actually doing? First time i see it.

Comment: It is an implicit type definition. Basically since you are creating a new instance of type BaseWeapon, the compiler knows the type of your variable. You can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx